# Get the first line of a file, trim characters and replace other characters

Tags: bash

I have a .bat file which is just 1 line long which cd's to a directory, e.g:
    cd C:\directory1\directory2

Is there a command I can run to extract the path only (not the cd or whitespace), as well as replacing the backslashes with forward slashes so I can use the path to cd in my bash script?

So essentially the output I would need would be:
    C:/directory1/directory2

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried any command?

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` and `sed`

```
awk '{ print $2 }' filename.bat | sed -e 's/\\/\//g'
```

The `awk` sentence will take only the path and that `sed` command will change backslashes with forward slashes.

Another way with `cut` and `tr`:

```
cut -d' ' -f2 filename.bat | tr '\\' '\/'
```

Same logic than before.